# bootstrap-select getting value at backend

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

I have a simple selector

```
<select class="selectpicker">
 <option>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
   <option>Barbecue</option>
</select>
```

This is inside a form and I am using  bootstrap-select  for selecting multiple values for this drop down.

Any idea how to multiple values at **back-end** ?

I am able to get value if only one option is selected

If you choose multiple and try to get the object by id in my backend code (Java) only one option is coming instead of multiple options

Comment: [RTFM](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) please!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the [manual](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/)!!!

```
<select class="selectpicker" multiple>
    <option>Mustard</option>
    <option>Ketchup</option>
    <option>Relish</option>
</select>
```

[image]

Use the attribute `multiple` with the `<select>` tag!

Comment: Thanks for the reply.   I am asking how to get multiple values at the back-end?   If you choose multiple and try to get the object by id my backend code (Java) only one option is coming instead of multiple options

Comment: Okay, for that, you need to append your `<select>`'s `name` with `[]`. Try it and it gives you an array!